# Sort one column by another and keep proceeding rows in the same order

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

So I have this excel spreadsheet that has a few verbs in Spanish as well as their conjugations:

```
Order  Infinitive  conjugation1 conjugation2 conjugation3 conjugation4 conjugation5 conjugation6 

ir     |   ser      soy          eres         es           somos        sois         son

ser    |  hacer     hago         haces        hace         hacemos      haceis       hacen

hacer  |   ir           voy          vas          va           vamos        vais         van
```

My goal is to sort the Infinitive column by the Order column and have the conjugation columns (conjugation1-conjugation7) stay in the same order

```
Order  Infinitive  conjugation1 conjugation2 conjugation3 conjugation4 conjugation5 conjugation6 <br><br>
ir     |   ir           voy          vas          va           vamos        vais         van

ser       |ser       soy             eres         es           somos        sois         son

hacer  | hacer    hago       haces        hace         hacemos      haceis       hacen
```

The row count on all of the columns is about 202 and all of the words in the Order column can be found in the Infinitive column. Any and all help is appreciated!!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You want each word in column 2 to match up to the same word in column 1 and take columns 3 through 8 with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is no duplication in the Infinitive column (word will only appear once?)

1. Insert a new column to the right of Order and list numbers 1-->202
2. Insert a new column to the right of that column and enter: `=B2&A2`
3. After that drag it down all the way to the bottom... the value will be displayed as "1ir", then "2ser", then "3hacer", etc.
4. Insert a new column the right of that column and enter: `=VLOOKUP(E2,$A$2:$C$4,3,FALSE)` This will do a lookup of the Infinitive value in E2 which is "ser" in the "Order" column and return the Joined value "2ser"
5. Drag it down to the bottom of the list... they will be displayed "2ser", then "3hacer", then "1ir".
6. Then select column D and all the conjugations and sort them using column D

[image]